# EWS - ServerVersionInfo Version attribute in responses

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633705(v=exchg.80).aspx

> In each EWS response, the version of Exchange that generated the response is indicated by the ServerVersionInfo element. The following example shows a ServerVersionInfo element that represents a response from Exchange 2010 SP1.

The example on that page has:

> Version="Exchange2010_SP1"

I'm currently working with an Exchange Online account, and the value I'm seeing in EWS server responses is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo [xmlns' snipped]
MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="800" MinorBuildNumber="16"
Version="V2_6"/>
  </s:Header>
```

So it's Version="V2_6", which I can't find in the EWS reference.

1 - Is this to be expected for Exchange Online? What about Office 365 accounts?

2 - Where does V2_6 fit into the sequence of: Exchange2007, Exchange2007_SP1, Exchange2010, .... Exchange2013?

In other words, when I see Version="V2_6" in server responses, what schema version can I use in my requests' <RequestServerVersion>?

Comment: Documentation states that "Version" is the Schema Version, not what you send in the Request Version.

Comment: The request version is dependent on the operation you want to use and not the version of the server targeted; "newer" operations are not supported by older versions of exchange, and they will get rejected (SOAP fault).  The Exchange version numbers are all documented on MSDN, you must perform one operation to obtain the server version info, determine your feature set based on that, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same issue with a `V2_22` version number being returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404119/exchange-server-version-v2-22-returned-for-office-365-breaks-pattern-consequ).

Quoting from answers to [my question at the Exchange Server development forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2420092b-a68f-4475-9396-b90e39712c7d/exchangeonlineewsewsxml-exchange-server-version-v222-returned-for-office-365-breaks?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment):

"Exchange for Office 365 [ed: *Exchange Online*] has its own life (custom build) so it does not follow the Exchange 2013 version except for the major version."

You can use the `Exchange2013` RequestServerVersion when doing requests to the Office 365 EWS API. If you don't want to do that:
FreeRangeEggs suggest in his answer (here) to rely on MajorVersion, but the answer from Glen Scales (there) says to use AutoDiscovery to detect what schemas are supported.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `Version="Exchange2010_SP1"` is only for sending the requests, and not part of the response.

```
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
</soap:Header>
```

The request version does not match the response version, and is wrapped in different tags.

```
<h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15"
                     MinorVersion="0"
                     MajorBuildNumber="785"
                     MinorBuildNumber="6"
                     Version="V2_6"
                     xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I was going to suggest you use the `MajorVersion`, but that has only been available from 2010 up.

Comment: That's not what the documentation at that link says:

> In each EWS **response**, the version of Exchange that generated the **response** is indicated by the ServerVersionInfo element. The following example shows a ServerVersionInfo element that represents a **response** from Exchange 2010 SP1.

RequestServerVersion Version=... in requests

ServerVersionInfo Version=... in responses